# calling standard python functions from rubypython

Tags: python, ruby, rubypython

I am trying to use the rubypython gem.  Not sure how to call standard python functions like len and set.  In the python examples I see len(text3) and set(text3).

How do I call these in rubypython?

Here is the link to rubypython: http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation on that site?

Comment: I did read the overview, which had limited examples.  Since I am not familar with python, kind of difficult to read the reference.  Anyway, I found waht I was looking for - see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyPython::PyMainClass has a public instance method builtin()
You can use that to call the standard functions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, my Ruby knowledge is limited, and my knowledge of the `rubypython` gem is non-existent. However, I do know the standard functions you refer to a part of the `__builtin__` module, which is automatically imported into the python namespace. Fortunately, there's nothing preventing you from importing it explicitly again (which is perfectly safe in Python). You then *might* be able do something like `__builtin__.set()`. No guarantees, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to find a method to access the __builtin__ namespace.  I can now call the standard python methods.  The odds of posting here and finding the related information are probably close to 0 :-)